# Weird LibreOffice problem/bug with the word "developer"

Tags: libreoffice

So, Im writing a LibreOffice document which has the word "developer" written on the text; but there is a weird thing where whenever i type the word "developer", the "e" and the "r" come really really close. It's only for the word "developer" (i tried words like "manufacturer", "gamer" and they are all fine). Also, whenever I remove a letter from the word, like the "d" or the "v", the "e" and the "r" go back to normal.

Im on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Im using the default LibreOffice

It may be a stupid question, but i cant find an answer

Comment: @user68186 - I have experienced strange letter spacing bugs in Libreoffice as well...

Comment: @user68186 There, ive edited the question with all i know